# Internationalized string in JTextArea

Tags: java, internationalization, jtextarea, non-english

How can I display any non-English characters in JTextArea? I tried different ways, but none works. The following code prints gibberish for any non-English character like Japanese. In debug mode, the variable msgUtf8Str indeed shows the local characters correctly. The supporting character set can be large and a sample includes: Japanese, Chinese (Mandarin), French, German etc.

```
String msgUtf8Str = null;
byte[] msgUtf8= message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
try
{
    msgUtf8Str = new String(msgUtf8, "UTF-8");
}
catch(Exception ex){}       
txtMsg.append(msgUtf8Str + "\n");
```

Comment: Where do you get your string to display? Are you reading this from a file? On what computer are you doing this? Can it display non-English characters in other programs?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I am able to write the non-English string in a file. It's the UTF-8 charset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all of that code except the last line.

You are using the UTF-8 charset to translate `message` into bytes, which you are then translating back into a String using the same charset.  In other words, you have made a pointless round-trip conversion.

The original String, `message`, is already suitable for displaying non-English characters.  You do not need to use Charsets in any way.

For instance:

```
String message = "\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e \u4e2d\u6587 Fran\u00e7ais f\u00fcr";
textMsg.append(message).append("\n");
```

Here is a small demo:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class I18NDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String message =
            "\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e \u4e2d\u6587 Fran\u00e7ais f\u00fcr";

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "message" is already non-English when I am reading it. So you are right -- I likely don't need to use Charset. However, it is not unicode either. There is a localized properties file that contains for example Japanese values. I am trying to show the values on the JTextArea. In summary, read Japanese text from a file and show on JTextArea. Can you please tell how?

Comment: What happens when you try to display the message?  Do you get an exception?  Do you see strange characters in the JTextArea, like "▯" or "�" or "?"?

Comment: I see strange characters just like you mentioned.

Comment: Have you changed the JTextArea's font?  What do you see if you set your JTextArea's font to `new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 12)`?